# Why does new EventEmitter().on("event", array.push) work unexpected

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does `new EventEmitter().on("event", array.push)` work unexpected

```
let array = [];
let a = new EventEmitter();
a.on("event", array.push);       
a.emit("event", 123);
setTimeout(console.log, 1000, array);

Expect: [123]
Actual: []
```

However, replacing `a.on("event", array.push);` with `a.on("event", (a) => { array.push(a); });` works

Comment: Because the array's `push()` method needs to have `this` point to the array. You can do this instead if you want `a.on("event", array.push.bind(array))`.

Comment: Thanks!! it solves my problem